# Stub a function of a function with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to stub a function of a function (well I need to stub both really)

Here is an example

```
return res.foo(100).bar(aVar)
```

and here is what my test mocking looks like

```
let res = {
    foo: ()=> jest.fn( {bar:()=> jest.fn()})
}
```

However when running my tests I get the error 'TypeError: res.foo(...).bar is not a function'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close.

Just three changes needed:

- `jest.fn()` returns a function so it doesn't need to be wrapped in a function
- `jest.fn()` takes an optional implementation parameter which should be a *function*
- If you want to spy on `bar` then return the *same spy* in the mock implementation of `foo`, otherwise a new `bar` spy gets created each time `foo` is called.

So your mock should look like this:

```
const barSpy = jest.fn();
let res = { foo: jest.fn(() => ({ bar: barSpy })) };
```

---

Here is a working demo:

```
const func = (res, aVar) => {
  return res.foo(100).bar(aVar);
}

test('stub chained functions', () => {
  const barSpy = jest.fn(() => 'the result');
  const res = { foo: jest.fn(() => ({ bar: barSpy })) };

  const result = func(res, 'a var');

  expect(res.foo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(100);  // SUCCESS
  expect(barSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('a var');  // SUCCESS
  expect(result).toBe('the result');  // SUCCESS
})
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much!